# Append data to text file

Tags: python

I have a text file with name/score pairs. This has a name and corresponding score delimited with a tab, and each name/score pair on a line of its own.

If I want to add a new person's result, how do I write the new name/score pair to the text file to preserve this layout?

I read the data from the text file and place it in a dictionary for use throughout the rest of the programme. It probably wouldn't be a good idea to just write the entire dictionary to the text file, so I thought the new details could be stored in a list and then written to the file. I just can't get the format right.

Comment: What did you try, and what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of explaining the input data, show a sample of it. Also, you really need to show your code and explain within your code what is currently not working. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This link is a nice tutorial on modes of reading and writing: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

If you are using plain text for your values, open the file with 'a'

```
with open(filename, 'a') as file:
    file.write(new_stuff)
    #Where 'new_stuff' is a string of what you want to write in it
```

Answer (score 0):

like earlier answer but new _stuff in format you asked for:

```
name = 'sdf'
score = 5
new_stuff = '%s\t%d\n' % (name, score)

with open(filename, 'a') as file:
    file.write(new_stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get you started:

```
with open(r"\path\to\scores.txt", 'a') as f:
    f.write(name + "\t" + score + "\n")
```

This is going to open the file `scores.txt` ready to append some data (`'a'`).

Now that the file is open we are going to write the persons name, followed by a tab (`"\t"`), followed by their score, and then a new line (`"\n"`). It will give an output similar to this:

```
Name    7
```

You will probably need to modify this slightly to use your own variable names.